# PHP how to use range() for float numbers

Tags: php

Is there a way to use PHP `range()` for a really small number? like below?

```
range(0.54,0.58);
```

Doing this creates an error.

> range(): step exceeds the specified range in

Comment: what do you want??

Comment: Range function default step is 1. So the error comes.

Comment: Let me add another answer first with the same result!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The third parameter is the `step`.
Reading the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) is a very good place to start.

If you read you will see that you can set the step to something that can increment between your limits.
The error message is simply telling you that it cannot increment 0.54 by 1 without going over 0.58 - think about, it 1 + 0.54 is more than 0.58!

Using this line instead will give you the desired output.

```
range(0.54, 0.58, 0.01);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should also provide the range you want.

Like this

`var_dump(range(0.54,0.58,0.01));`

output is

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  float(0.54)
  [1]=>
  float(0.55)
  [2]=>
  float(0.56)
  [3]=>
  float(0.57)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message is self-explanatory: the default value of `$range` (the third argument of [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)) is `1` and using it produces an empty range.

Provide a third argument to [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php). From the value of `$start` and `$end` I think `0.01` is the step you need:

```
range(0.54, 0.58, 0.01)
```

Check it out: https://3v4l.org/IcUAh

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, so I was missing the increment property of the function.

Answer (score 1):

use the third parameter to set a step

range(0.54,0.58, 0.01);

or you could multiply your values by 1000 and then divide by 1000 which would be silly...

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here did not work for me as, due to rounding error with floats, the result is not exact:

- Depending on the start and end numbers the result is inclusive or exclusive the end number.
- Additionally in PHP 8 the rounding errors are visible in the result. (Seams to [only apply to debug output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69860831/1629120).)

**Examples:**

php 7.4: (inclusive vs. exclusive)

```
php > var_dump(range(0.54, 0.6, 0.01));  
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  float(0.54)
  [1]=>
  float(0.55)
  [2]=>
  float(0.56)
  [3]=>
  float(0.57)
  [4]=>
  float(0.58)
  [5]=>
  float(0.59)
}
php > var_dump(range(0.52, 0.6, 0.01)); 
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  float(0.52)
  [1]=>
  float(0.53)
  [2]=>
  float(0.54)
  [3]=>
  float(0.55)
  [4]=>
  float(0.56)
  [5]=>
  float(0.57)
  [6]=>
  float(0.58)
  [7]=>
  float(0.59)
  [8]=>
  float(0.6)
}
```

php 8.0: (inclusive vs. exclusive + rounding errors)

```
php > var_dump(range(0.54, 0.6, 0.01));
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  float(0.54)
  [1]=>
  float(0.55)
  [2]=>
  float(0.56)
  [3]=>
  float(0.5700000000000001)
  [4]=>
  float(0.5800000000000001)
  [5]=>
  float(0.5900000000000001)
}
php > var_dump(range(0.52, 0.6, 0.01));
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  float(0.52)
  [1]=>
  float(0.53)
  [2]=>
  float(0.54)
  [3]=>
  float(0.55)
  [4]=>
  float(0.56)
  [5]=>
  float(0.5700000000000001)
  [6]=>
  float(0.5800000000000001)
  [7]=>
  float(0.5900000000000001)
  [8]=>
  float(0.6)
}
```

**Solution:**

This does give my expected result (PHP 7.4 and up):

```
php > var_dump(array_map(fn($n) => $n/100, range(0.54*100, 0.6*100,  0.01*100)));
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  float(0.54)
  [1]=>
  float(0.55)
  [2]=>
  float(0.56)
  [3]=>
  float(0.57)
  [4]=>
  float(0.58)
  [5]=>
  float(0.59)
  [6]=>
  float(0.6)
}
```